# Xml create a value entry

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, numbers

I guess it a pretty basic thing, but i just cant seem to find a sloution for this:

if i write from my WPF application in c# to a xml doc, i use for example this line to create text (string).
`XmlText xmlTextScore = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("this is text");`

but now there is this case: there are these values 0, 6, and 12
sow if i sort the column, 6 will be on top, then 12, and then the 0.
So it seems it only looks at the first number to sort it on.

Now what i cant find, is, if there is a way to write values like int or double to the xml file, or if i should somehow tell the table that it is values it is sorting?

this is an example of what happens now:
[image: http://www.aqua-page.nl/dls/dls/images_new/example_score.PNG]

***EDIT 1***

Im directly reading the XML into the datafields. Isn't there a way to use something as Parse for each cell in that specific column before i call the sorting ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the table is sorted alphabetically rather than numerically. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453721/numerical-string-sorting-in-a-listbox) is a similar question with an approved answer.

Comment: mm, im directly reading the XML into the datafields. Isn't there a way to use something as Parse for each cell in that specific column before i call the sorting ?