# wpf propertygrid sorts array in alphabetic order when expanded. Anyway to order it in numerical order?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, sorting

wpf propertygrid sorts array in alphabetic order when expanded. 0,1,10,11...2,20... 
Anyway to order it in numerical order in the propertygrid? I have tried CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView to define a custom sort but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Share what you tried so far.

Comment: Does this help?:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453721/numerical-string-sorting-in-a-listbox

Comment: I think your answer is [ICustomTypeDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert) is a good example

Comment: I have tried the following but nothing has worked. 
1. 
ListCollectionView _arrView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TestList) as ListCollectionView;
_arrView.CustomSort = new IntSorter();
2.
Implement ICustomTypeDescriptor in my collection which calls a custom property descriptor class to get property names and values. I can write a custom propertydescriptioncollection and provide a IComparer interface but that doesn't seem to work.
This option is really no good for plain arrays because this option would require me to create a collection class that inherits from other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to sort the array in numerical order but I have created a workaround.

Step1: Create a collection that implements ICustomTypeDescriptor. Well described here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert

Step2. Use the following override for PropertyDescriptor property.

```css
public override string DisplayName {
  get {
    string formatStr="D" + this.collection.Count.ToString().Length.ToString();
    return"[" + index.ToString(formatStr) +"]";
  }
}
```

This gives displaynames to collection items as [001][002]... which works when sorted alphabetically by the propertygrid.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Linq  [Enumerable.OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx)

It let you specify any [comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Just do your own :

```
public class NumericComparer: IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
    {
        if (IsNumeric(s1) && IsNumeric(s2))
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(s1) > Convert.ToInt32(s2)) return 1;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(s1) < Convert.ToInt32(s2)) return -1;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(s1) == Convert.ToInt32(s2)) return 0;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsNumeric(string value)
    {
        try 
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            return true; 
        }
        catch (FormatException) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Example :

```
Enumerable.OrderBy(x => x, new NumericComparer());
```

Comment: I don't get it. How would you link this with propertygrid? I am having a problem sorting the propertygrid. Even if I sort the the items in propertygrid remain sorted in alphabetical order